# Cant connect MongoDB Ubuntu 18.04 bionic

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I've got an old PC with an some old mongo shell. So I've deleted all mongo files couple times but I still have problems with mongoDB connection, please help.
So I've put in the bash this command

```
`mongo`
```

and getting this

```
`MongoDB shell version v4.2.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-12-15T20:30:51.284+0300 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2019-12-15T20:30:51.286+0300 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2019-12-15T20:30:51.286+0300 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1`
```

When I'm trying to use this command

```
`mongod`
```

I've got this

```
`2019-12-15T20:34:10.275+0300 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-12-15T20:34:10.278+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=13850 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=student
2019-12-15T20:34:10.278+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.2
2019-12-15T20:34:10.278+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a0bbbff6ada159e19298d37946ac8dc4b497eadf
2019-12-15T20:34:10.278+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
2019-12-15T20:34:10.278+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-12-15T20:34:10.278+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-12-15T20:34:10.278+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-12-15T20:34:10.278+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2019-12-15T20:34:10.278+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-12-15T20:34:10.278+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-12-15T20:34:10.278+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-12-15T20:34:10.279+0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2019-12-15T20:34:10.279+0300 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-12-15T20:34:10.279+0300 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2019-12-15T20:34:10.279+0300 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2019-12-15T20:34:10.279+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-12-15T20:34:10.279+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100`
```

Please Help me to start my local mongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the mongod log!

`Data directory /data/db not found`

This means, that mongodb did not find the data dirctory.
Probably this directory is defined in the mongod configuration.
This is the reason why mongod does not start. So you cant connect  to the server (`mongod`) using the client (`mongo`), because no server is running.

You have to define a valid data directory in your mongod configurarion

Answer (score 0):

when starting mongodb on your computer you should include the directory eg `mongod --dbpath /username/data/db`